# Can I acquire the generation I starter Pokemon in White 2 / Black 2?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

It's been quite some time since I've played a Pokemon game. In fact, I was in elementary or middle school when Red/Blue was all the rage here.

Is there anyway to acquire Pikachu, Squirtle, Charmander, or Bulbasaur in White/Black 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No.** Pikachu, Squirtle, Charmander and Bulbasaur can only be obtained in Black/White 2 by trade, or special events.

Ways to obtain Pikachu and the Red/Blue starters in BW2 include:

- Time-limited Wi-Fi, Global Link and Dream World events: keep an eye on [Bulbanews' events listing](http://bulbanews.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Front_page/Events). For example, you can currently download the Red/Blue starters if you have a Korean copy of Black/White, or Pikachu if you buy the game on Amazon UK. At time of writing, there are no English language events for these Pokémon.
- Find someone online who will trade you one - quite easy, since Pokémon can be bred. You can't use the GTS for this, though, because you can't request a Pokémon you haven't seen
- Trade from an earlier game using Poké Transfer:

  - Professor Oak gives you a Bulbasaur, Charmander or Squirtle in HeartGold or SoulSilver when you defeat Red
  - You get a Bulbasaur, Charmander or Squirtle as a starter in FireRed and LeafGreen
  - Pikachu can be caught in every main series Pokémon game on the GBA and DS, prior to Black/White

Interestingly, Black and White are the first main series Pokémon games where you can't catch Pikachu - except for Yellow, technically, where you receive one as a starter.

Answer (score 2):

You can acquire them only via Poké Transfer.

Answer (score 1):

From what I know, it's only possible by Poké Transfer or Wi-Fi trade.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't get Bulbasaur, Charmander or Squirtle in Black/White 2, but it is possible to get different starters in B/W 2 than just the B/W starters.

However for Pikachu, you can get a Pichu in Black/White, which you can evolve into Pikachu and trade to B/W 2.

Comment: @Robotnik Please don't edit non-answers into answers.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot - The user posted two answers, one a reply of the other. I combined them and flagged the other for removal

Comment: @Robotnik Why would you flag the attempted answer instead of the non-answer?  All you're doing is invalidating other users' flags.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot - Why does it matter? both were posted within minutes of each other. The user 'replied' to him/herself. It was originally written A1: "No you can't, but you can get others" A2: "Oh, but you can get pikachu". Both were valid answers (not very good ones, but valid)

Comment: @Robotnik Basically, what you did was combine two non-answers into a well written, acceptable answer. That's not how editing works. If it had gone to the review queue, it would've been the very definition of "Radical Change." This should not have been edited.

Comment: @Robotnik This was originally not an answer in any sense.

Comment: @Fluttershy - technically I made two edits - one to combine them, and one to fix the wording/grammar/formatting. Because they were under the 5 minute window they appear as one. OrigamiRobot - 'No you can't' *is* actually an answer to the question. Formatting aside, the content was there.

Comment: @Robotnik This answer was originally "i know its of topic but is there diferant starters in b/w 2 than just b/w"  I don't see how you're getting "No you can't" from that.

Comment: @Fluttershy  - All of this aside, if the entire point of allowing community edits is to improve the post, why revert an "acceptable answer" into a "non-answer"? (your words)

Comment: @OrigamiRobot - I must've originally interpreted it that way, I dunno how. My bad then.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to get the Kanto/Johto/Hoenn/Sinnoh starters by talking to the clown in Virbank City and in Castelia City (Battle Company 55th floor). We can also get the special starters depending on the season (in-game). I already got Piplip and Charmander during winter.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible I got a level 1 wartortle in the shaking grass in the rain 
 And bulbasaur apears at level 1 quiet often as well .. charmander is the only one I haven't found

Comment: Sounds like you have a game that is hacked or something... :s

Answer (score -2):

I found out you can get the kanto,jhoto and heon starters in black 2 and white 2 locations are next to Rosie's gym there should be a clown there but it depends on the season also you can find a clown in the battle company and there's a third but I can't remember we're that one is

Comment: I meant the second gym leader